# Winforms c#: Using a single parent for multiple Forms

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, winforms, parent

I have two forms (for example Form1 and Form2) in my project and I run only one form depending on a value which is read from a .txt file in Program.cs.

The two forms have the same controls and I am wondering if I can call the controls in a workerThread (inside the class Fsm.cs) using the **same** **parent** definition for both the forms.

For example: the control TextBox1 is defined in Form1 and Form2, but I want call in the workerThread DoWork() only the parent control  associated to the running form:

```
 parent.TextBox1.Visible = true;
```

Where **parent** can be Form1 or Form2.

How can I use the same parent definition mutually in Fsm.cs? 
I don't want to define two different thread functions for the two forms.

Here there is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        form2 = new Form2();
        InitializeComponent();
        workerObject = new Fsm(this, form2);
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(workerObject.DoWork);
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        form1 = new Form1();
        InitializeComponent();
        workerObject = new Fsm(form1, this);
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(workerObject.DoWork);
     }
 }


 public class Fsm 
 {
     public Form1 parent;
     public Form2 parent1;

     public Fsm(Form1 p, Form2 p1)
     {
         parent = p;
         parent1 = p1;
     }

     public void DoWork()
     {
         parent.TextBox1.Visible = true;
     }
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: If the forms have the same controls, why do you have two Form classes at all? If there are differences and similarities between the two forms, capture what is equal in a common interface of which both classes derive and use this interface in your Fsm class.

Comment: Note that in Winforms `Parent` is usually the container a control is placed inside; nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: You **cannot** call methods on a `Control` from a background thread.  You could use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` to marshal over first.

Comment: @KlausGütter What do you mean with common interface? I need 2 Forms because they are used for 2 different monitor resolution and also they do not share all the controls.

Comment: But you wrote in your question that both forms have the same controls. And now in a comment you state it is not so. Please update your question with the correct information

Comment: @GuidoG Sorry with "do not share" I mean that some controls are hidden for a Form and not for another but I create the same controls for both.

Comment: I think what you need to do is design one form, with all the code and controls that both forms share. Then you inherit the 2 forms from this one. This way you have only one form to maintain for all the shared code and controls. Its just basic inheritance

Comment: Thank you @GuidoG. Do you have an example of this inheritance? Sorry but I am new in c# coding.

Comment: Its called `Visual Inheritance` if you search for that you will find many examples, and also information about any problems you might get. This technique is very old and its a shame that the designer of visual studio does such a bad job on this. Anyway, for simple forms with just one level of inheritance you should be just fine

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/windows-forms-visual-inheritance

Comment: @GuidoG thank you a lot. This can solve my problem!